# Outlook 2016 - Selecting calendar when creating an appointment

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

Like many of us, I have multiple mailboxes in my Outlook and thus multiple calendars.

When I create a new appointment, from the Appointment dialog, how can I assign to which of my calendars the event is going to be saved? And of course without selecting the calendar before creating the Appointment!

Comment: Typically, this is done by making the calendar you wish the event to be created in active before clicking the New Event/Meeting/Appointment button. But I'm interested to learn if there are other ways as well because my staff deal with this issue.

Comment: There does not appear to be a way to do what you want.  What music2myear said looks like the fastest solution.

Comment: This is what I am currently trying to do but it is far from perfect. For example if you press CTRL-SHIFT-A without first going to your calendar view. Same when opening a .ICS file to create an appointment to your calendar. I hope there is another way!

Comment: I know there is a way to set Outlook to default to an account when sending emails. You can also set Outlook to prompt which account to use, which I remember is done via a macro. You may consider whether it is possible via coding. (Sorry not good at programming :-( )

Comment: Hi Steve. We can add the "From" field when we compose a new email (and it doesn't have to be through coding). I am looking for the exact same thing for appointments which I never found.